# How can I detach a stream from a stream reader or stream writer?

Tags: c#, .net, io

I have a class which accepts a stream as input (in the constructor). It surfaces content from this stream through various methods.

However, I don't want my object to be responsible for closing the stream -- that should be the responsibility of the caller. I therefore need to close my StreamReader inside my class, but I can't close the underlying stream.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need to close the StreamReader?

Comment: @Martinho: Because to my understanding that's what you're supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StreamReader`s are designed to take complete and sole ownership of the underlying stream.

In particular, the `StreamReader` will arbitrarily read ahead in the stream to fill an internal buffer.  (This bit me once)

If you need to share the stream, you probably shouldn't use a `StreamReader` at all.

Comment: @SLacks: Generally speaking, I don't share the streamreader at all. The only place I need this is for unit testing a class representing a mount point.

Answer (score 4):

Closing the streamreader will close the underlying stream.  There is no way around that.  However, the *only* reason you need to close a streamreader is so that the underlying stream is also closed.  The rest of it is all managed code.  That means you can just abandon your streamreader and everything should be fine — assuming your caller remembers to close their stream as they should.

Comment: @Billy: Finalizers should only dispose _native_ resources.